Strange navigation behavior .htaccess
My .htaccess:
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myblog/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^notes/?$ note.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^notes/([^/]*)?$ note.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/?$ book.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^books/([^/]*)?$ book.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

Normally, my navigation sidebar behaves like this dynamically:
127.0.0.1/myblog/<sub-entry> 

<sub-entry> = books or notes
Now in my notes.php I have a sample "notes/persistence" link that upon clicking navigates to: 127.0.0.1/myblog/notes/persistence. But, upon this navigation, I notice that when I hold the mouse over the options of navigation, the following appears down on the left corner of the browser:
127.0.0.1/myblog/notes/notes
127.0.0.1/myblog/notes/books

When it is supposed to say:
127.0.0.1/myblog/notes
127.0.0.1/myblog/books

Why does this behavior happen?
